# How to make line breaks strictly under the numbering line in Notepad++?

Tags: windows, notepad++, edit

How to make line breaks strictly under the numbering line? The screenshot shows that the first line is moved to the beginning of the next one. But subsequent lines are strictly indented:

[image]

How to make the first line move under number 1)?

Answer (score 2):

Notepad++ will only auto-insert subsequent indents if you manually indent the first line in a block.

The preferences for *Notepad++ Version 8.5.6* are shown below.

[image]

#### Update:

Please take into account that Notepad++ is a text editor with many functions but not a program like Microsoft Word. I recommend using a simple structured numbering.

The cause here may depend on several settings. In the main menu also check your setting View > Word wrap.

Switched ***off (not checked)*** leads to the following view:

[image]

Switched ***on (checked)*** leads to the following view:

[image]

Please note, another setting for `Line Wrap` you should adjust for your needs.

`Align`: Lines are broken and the following lines start in the same column as the first line.

[image]

`Indent`: Inserts a tabulation in front of the lines

[image]

Comment: I set the settings to the same as yours, but the problem remained. As far as I understand, this is due to line breaks. In the first line, words are moved to the beginning of a new line. And the lines below, starting with `2)`, are moved under the numbers. If I remove `1.`, then all the lines will move exactly under the numbers.

Comment: Yes, a line break is essential in the first line. But there are many other settings that influence the appearance (see update in my answer).

Comment: Enabling the `Indent` option partially solved my problem. But then the lines under the numbers `2)`, `1)`, `2)` are also shifted to the right. I need them to stay strictly under the numbers.